# Can sending message to Kafka asynchronously effect message ordering?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

This is my understanding of sending messages to Kafka asynchronously and implementing a callback function is:

**Scenario**: Producer is going to receive 4 batches of messages to send (to same partition, for the sake of simplicity).

Producer sends batch A.

Producer sends batch B.

Producers receives reply from broker and implements call back - batch A was unsuccessful and retriable, batch B was successful, so producer sends batch A again.

Won't this disturb the message ordering as now A is received by Kafka after B?

Comment: Is the message order important then? Do the orders have a connection to each other. If not than it does not mather what order they will be received, they will just be handled independently from each other.

Comment: For this question's sake, let's assume ordering is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you need message ordering within partition you can use idempotent producer:

```
enable.idempotence=true
akcs=all
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection<=5 
retries>0
```

This will resolve potential duplicates from producer and maintain the ordering.

If you don't want to use idempotent producer then it is enough to set `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`. This is the number of unacknowledged batches on the producer side. It means that batch B will not be sent before acknowledge for A is received.

Comment: But my question was that in the scenario I have mentioned, can that result in wrong message ordering?
And also, setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1, won't this in a sense make producer act as synchronous instead of asynchronous?

Comment: The answer is that it depends on your producer configuration. In the new versions of Kafka producers are idempotent by default. Having max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1 means the number of unacknowledged batches,  but communication with the server happens asynchronously in the background thread.

Comment: You still have a queue system. Without Kafka you would not have that. So if a lot of requests are coming into your back-end. The requests will be saved and consumed whenever the back-end is ready for the request to be consumed. This will prevent any request loss or timeouts, and is also part of the asynchronous idea of Kafka or any message queue system.

Comment: @KatyaGorshkova but having the number of unacknowledged batches as 1, doesn't it make it synchronous? Producer sends batch 1 and now has to wait for response (since m.i.f.r.p.c = 1) before sending batch B?

Comment: Strictly speaking it is asynchronous anyway as batch is created per <topic,partition> , so batches for these combinations can be created simultaneously. But for sure having m.i.f.r.p.c = 1 slows it down. With the idempotent producer however you can have up to 5 unacknowledged batches.